# Queueing Analysis Arrival Rate Gamma distribution

Tags: queueing-theory, gamma-distribution, python

I want to write a program in python that simulates a queueing system.

I have a G/M/1 queue.
For the service time, I chose expovariate(1.0).
For the interarrival time, I chose gammavariate(2.0,a).
I change a to different values to make a curve about the arrival rate.
But what is the arrival rate of that distribution?

I know that the arrival rate $\lambda$ equals $\frac{1}{E[A]}$, with A the interarrival time. However what is the mean of this interarrival time, if it is a gamma distribution like gammavariate(2,a) in python?

Comment: Please show your try at the problem in order to get better response from the community.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco I added my question a bit, I know that the arrival rate equals 1 divided by the mean of the interarrival rate but i still can't answer as I do not know the mean of gammavariate(2,a)